# transform.position vector only changing when out of scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, position, transform

This is my first legitimate issue that I am having with coding and I don't know where to find an answer.

I have an object that I need to move in the X dimension as time goes on.  Here is the following code that I have.

```
Vector3 temp = transform.position;
temp.x += forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.position = temp;
```

When I debug I can see that temp.x is not changing. However, when I move the object out of the camera area the X starts to change. If this isn't enough information please let me know and I will provide more code or what ever I need to show. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you look at the variables you tried modifying `temp.x` with? Also assuming the example is complete, there's no need for the copy `transform.position.x += forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime;` <- note obviously this will only work if you only care about moving the object along the world x axis.

Comment: When I do that I get this error `Cannot modify a value type return value of 'UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable` So I use the temp in order to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `Vector3 temp = transform.position`, it returns a copy of the transform.position.
In your case, the proper way of changing the X position should be like this:

```
transform.position += (Vector3.right * forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Where Vector3.right is the [shorthand of writing Vector3(1, 0, 0)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-right.html).
This way, you ensure that the statement is updating the transform.position vector, not a copy of it.